# Play 60fps video at 30fps

Tags: mpv

I have a 60fps 1080p video from a GoPro that is playing really choppily in mpv (and other media players).  How can I make mpv drop every other frame to get a smoother video?

Alternatively, is there any fast way to convert the video to 30fps?

Comment: Yes, You can build a new video at 30 FPS use your video editing software of your choice

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm using `ffmpeg -r 30`, but speed is at 0.05. At this rate it's going to take all day.  Is there any **fast** way to convert the video to 30fps?

Comment: Any method will require the software to go through every frame but also note that you have to adjust your audio also.

Comment: Is playback choppy because your PCs specs are insufficient for 1080p60? In that case, converting will of course also take a *very* long time.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to this part of the question: "Alternatively, is there any fast way to convert the video to 30fps".

By [this answer over at video processing](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/32908/33429) it should be possible to "loselessly" throw away some B and P frames without slow re-encoding. It was [originally proposed here](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/21431/33429) and would be execute like this:

```
ffmpeg -discard noref -i input.mp4 -c copy -vsync 0 reduced.mp4
```

The second link claims this is supported for h264. As h265 support is being integrated into ffmpeg on a feature-by-feature basis, ffmpeg 4.2.4 I had at hand cannot do this for h265 (yet).

---

UPDATE: Actually, mpv can pass this lavc option directly. And it works even for h265 files:

```
mpv --vd-lavc-skipframe=[nonref|bidir|nonkey]
```

- "--vd-lavc-skipframe=nonref" does not seem to skip substantial amount of frames
- "--vd-lavc-skipframe=bidir" skips all B-frames, which leaves only a few frames per second
- "--vd-lavc-skipframe=nonref" leaves only I-frames, which turns the video into a slideshow

Summary: It can't do 30 FPS, but it allows viewing low-action h265@60 videos older hardware.

Comment: Does also work with hardware decoding (vaapi accel and gpu vo): `mpv --hwdec=auto --framedrop=decoder --vd-lavc-skipframe=nonref` – A total game-changer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mpv --framedrop=vo <video>`. This should hopefully do what you want. If you look at the mpv manual and search for `framedrop`, you will also see that there are some other options (that are "not recommended"). I could imagine that `--framedrop=decoder` might help, if your PC is too slow to decode the video, for example.